# How can I change the color of a specific cell in a table using html in SQL server 2012?

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, html-table

I am using html code in my SQL Script to output results from a table in an email, but I need to change the color of the text if any of the results come back as specific string. Here is a snippet of what I'm using to produce the table:

```
'<table border="2">' + 
                      '<tr>
                          <th>No#</th>
                          <th>SERVER NAME</th> 
                          <th>SERVER IP</th>
                          <th>STATUS </th>
                      </tr>' +
                      CAST (( SELECT DISTINCT
                               td = [NUMBER],                              '',
                               td = [SERVER NAME],                         '',
                               td = [SERVER IP],                           '',
                               td = [STATUS],                   ''
                          FROM SUMMARY
                      FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE 
                          ) AS VARCHAR(MAX) ) +
'</table>';
```

So I am concerned about the "STATUS" Field, if it comes back SUCCESS it could stay as regular text, if it says BAD then I want it to be Red.... I have tried putting in the      `<font color="">` tag but it only changes the Headers (between the TH tags)..

```
No# SERVER NAME SERVER IP   STATUS  
1   SERVER1     10.10.10.1  BAD         --this should be red
2   SERVER2     10.10.10.2  SUCCESS 
3   SERVER3     10.10.10.3  BAD         --this should be red
4   SERVER4     10.10.10.4  SUCCESS
```

Comment: SQL isnt a front-end language and should not be used as one. You should use PHP condition to change font color based on string. `STATUS` should only be `BAD`, or better: 1/0.

Answer (score 0):

Like the commenter noted, you should really not be doing this. If you really want to, you will need to do it outside the query, since SQL will treat all query data as text and escape the HTML characters in order to display them as text.

A simple (but "ugly-ish") solution is to simply do a replace like this:

```
REPLACE('<table border="2">' + 
                  '<tr>
                      <th>No#</th>
                      <th>SERVER NAME</th> 
                      <th>SERVER IP</th>
                      <th>STATUS </th>
                  </tr>' +
                  CAST (( SELECT DISTINCT
                           td = [NUMBER],                              '',
                           td = [SERVER NAME],                         '',
                           td = [SERVER IP],                           '',
                           td = [STATUS],                   ''
                      FROM SUMMARY
                  FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE 
                      ) AS VARCHAR(MAX) ) +
'</table>', '>BAD<', '><font color="red">BAD</font><')
```

Comment: Thank you, it is indeed a bit ugly-ish but it works!